# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, message

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("messageUpdate", async (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    var logchannel = client.channels.cache.get("736913251274719273");
    let logembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription(":wastebasket: Message Deleted")
        .addField("Message", message.content, true)
        .setTimestamp()

    logchannel.send(logembed)
})

client.login('token');
```

Comment: You have a reference to `message.author.tag` and `message.author.avatarURL`, but `message` is not defined anywhere.  It appears you probably want to use `newMessage` instead of `message`.  Also, there does not look like there's any reason for your callback to be declared `async` as you're not using `await` anywhere or using the promise returned from the `async` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is saying exactly what is your problem.

```
message.author.tag
```

`message` variable is used in several places of the function, but you didn't define the variable.